# How to authenticate blackduck API with CURL call

Tags: blackduck

I want to List the Black duck scan versions and I found API in blackduck API section and appended some headers as below.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"  https://<URL>/api/projects/${project_id}/versions


 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

After running above command I am getting above error. Is the API_TOKEN enough for authentication right or am i missing something here

Answer (score 0):

****The user token is not enough for authentication, follow steps below.****

Note that the bearer token has a timeout and should be updated !

### steps

Make a request that uses the user.

```
response=$(curl --insecure -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization: ${TOKEN}" https://<URL>/api/tokens/authenticate)
```

Extract Bearer Token

```
bearer_token=$(echo "${response}" | jq --raw-output '.bearerToken')
```

Use the bearer token to make API calls

```
curl --insecure -X GET --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization: bearer $bearer_token"  https://<URL>/api/projects/${project_id}/versions
```